# How to use cout to display a value from a class within a class?

Tags: c++, class, cout

Here are three different classes

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "registeredUser.h"

using namespace std;

class theater
{

public:

string address;

registeredUser registerUser(string e, string p)
{
    registeredUser y;
    y.email = e;
    y.password= p;

    return y;
}

};
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "userData.h"
#include "movie.h"
using namespace std;

class registeredUser
{
public:
    string email;
    string password;


movie addMovie(string t, int y, string d, string g)
{
    movie m;
    m.title = t;
    m.year = y;
    m.desc = d;
    m.genre = g;

    return m;
}

 userData addUserData(string n, string a, string cc)
 {
     userData y;
     y.name = n;
     y.address = a;
     y.creditCard = cc;

     return y;
 }


 };
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;

   class userData
   {
   public:
    string name;
    string address;
    string creditCard;
   };
```

What I've done in the code below is create an instance of a theater and then an instance of a registeredUser, within the instance of a theater. This user instance also has in it another class: userData.

```
// create a new theatre object
theater uweTheater;
uweTheater.address = "UWE Frenchay";

// register a user with the theatre and add some user details
registeredUser user1 = uweTheater.registerUser("user1@here.com", "password");
user1.addUserData("Name", "Address", "Number");
```

How can I use std::cout to display the inner most classes details? For example if I wanted to display the name of user1 how would I declare that in the cout statement -> std::cout << ?? << endl;

Comment: Implement `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const userData&)`?

Comment: BTW, your `Add*`/`Register*` functions, doesn't **add** element, but just create them. They probably just have to be constructor if the target class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `theater` class has a method called `registerUser()` which creates an instance of `registeredUser` and returns it. `registeredUser` similarly has a method called `addUserData()` which creates an instance of `userData` and returns it. The names for these methods are misleading because neither of them add or register a user with the outer class. Instead, they both just create an instance and return it.

I don't see a reason to separate `registeredUser` from `userData`. You should just create a `User` class with all the fields necessary for a user. You should also add a field to the `theater` class to keep track of all of its users. For example, you could do:

```
class theater {
    private:
        std:vector<User> users;
}
```

And then your `registerUser()` method can add users to this list of users.

Then to answer your question about printing information, you can override `operator>>()` for both classes to do this.